# Numerical range of unbounded symmetric but not selfadjoint operator!

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, spectral-theory

Assume we have a linear operator $A: \mathscr{H}\supseteq D(A) \rightarrow \mathscr{H}$ which is symmetric hence densely defined but not self adjoint. Where $\mathscr{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space.

The numerical range is defined as
$N(A):=\lbrace \langle Ax,x\rangle | x\in D(A), \|x\|=1\rbrace$

Then we know $cl(N(A))\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, because of the symmetry.

I wonder if $cl(N(A))=\mathbb{R}$. Because I came accross a statement that says that for a symmetric operators, which are not self adjoint, the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is either $\mathbb{C}$, $\lbrace{z\in\mathbb{C}| \mathrm{Im}(z)\geq 0}\rbrace$ or $\lbrace{z\in\mathbb{C}| \mathrm{Im}(z)\leq 0}\rbrace$.

But if that would be the case and $cl(N(A)) \subsetneqq \mathbb{R}$ we could find $z_0$ in some open and connected domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\setminus cl(N(A))$ where $\Omega\cap \sigma(A)\neq \emptyset$ (when $\sigma(A)=\lbrace{z\in\mathbb{C}| \mathrm{Im}(z)\leq 0}\rbrace$ or $\lbrace{z\in\mathbb{C}| \mathrm{Im}(z)\geq 0}\rbrace$). Where $\mathrm{ran}(z_0-A)=\mathscr{H}$ and thus $\Omega\subseteq \rho(A)$.

But this is a contradiction.

I also attached a picture to clarify my thoughts:

[image]

Comment: Why did you delete your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717609/numerical-method-for-simple-non-linear-ode? It was a good question.

Comment: Hi, this wasn't only my question and the other who was interested in this problem asked me to delete it. Because he don't want it to be public. ...But thanks for your help.